# Algorithm output to length starts new line

Tags: java, arrays, integer, string-formatting, system.out

I am trying to format the output from what I have written to display a list of primes (Eratosthenes) to a certain number results per line. Do they need to placed into an `Array` to accomplish this? I have not come across a way to implement their division besides `.split("");`, which would render a single line for each and the Oracle site's `System.out.format();` argument index to specify length. Yet, these require the characters to be known. I am printing it with the following, which of course creates an infinite line.

```
  for (int count = 2; count <= limit; count++) { 
        if (!match[count]) { 
            System.out.print(count + ", ");
        } 
   }
```

Is there a way to simply call `System.out.print("\n");` with an `if(...>[10]` condition when `System.out.print()` has run for instance 10 times? Perhaps I am overlooking something, relatively new to `Java`. Thanks in advance for any advice or input.

Comment: Keep track of how many primes you have displayed, then just do `System.out.println(); num = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply create some int value e.g.

```
int i = 1;
```

...and increment it's value everytime Sysout is running.

Something like this:

```
 int i = 1;
 for (int count = 2; count <= limit; count++) { 
    if (!match[count]) {
        if (i%10 == 0) 
            System.out.print(count+ "\n");
        else 
            System.out.print(count + ", ");
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Only addition is that `System.out.print(count + ", \n");` keeps the comma when `if` gets called.

Answer (score 2):

By using a tracker variable, you can keep track of how many items have been displayed already so you know when to insert a new line. In this case, I chose 10 items. The exact limit is flexible to your needs.

```
...
int num = 0;
//loop
for(int count = 2; count <= limit; count++)
{
    if(!match[count])
    {
        if (num == 10) { System.out.print("\n"); num = 0; }//alternatively, System.out.println();
        System.out.print(count + ",");
        num++;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This was a great solution. Thank you. (First line is reduced by 1).

Comment: Ah. You're right. I see the fix. Simple off-by-one, per usual.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int idx=1;
int itemsOnEachLine=10;
for(int count = 2; count <= limit; count++)
{
    if(!match[count])
    {
        System.out.print(count+(idx%itemsOnEachLine==0?"\n":","));
        idx++;
    }
}
```

you go increasing a counter (idx) along with every write, every 10 increments (idx modulus 10 == 0), you will be printing a new line character, else, a "," character.